# clearTimeout not working on keyup iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I know there are probably a lot of those questions already, but I looked through some of them, and i couldn't get a solution. I am currently working on a WYSIWYG editor, and I need to save when user does keyup.

I do not want it to update every change, but at max every two seconds. Could you tell me why this code is not working?

```
var updatetimer;
var body=$('#iframe').contents().find('body');
body.attr('contenteditable', true);
$(body).on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(updatetimer);
    updatetimer = setTimeout(function(){
        savepagetext();
    },2000);
});
```

It actually does work but fires `savepagetext()` every keyup. How to prevent this properly?

Comment: The code looks fine, could you setup a jsFiddle to replicate the problem?

Comment: Try replacing your body init by `var body= $('body', $('#iframe')[0].contentWindow.document);` (for IE, you will have to test contentDocument || contentWindow.document)

Comment: `clearTimeout` is a function of `window`. Your have to call `$('#iframe')[0].clearTimeout(updatetimer)` because the IFRAME is the `window` auf your timer

Comment: @drkunibar - you're right and you're wrong both at the same time...

Comment: @drkunibar `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLIFrameElement> has no method 'clearTimeout' ` (I'll be back in 3 hours, have to go)

Comment: @Ivotje50 - make sure **updatetimer** is global, e.g. use it as **window.updatetimer** everywhere. In general I'd like to advice you to avoid using global variables, and find a better solution...

Comment: Of cause - sorry. Use  `$('#iframe')[0].contentWindow.clearTimeout(updatetimer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with this code, using the global `window.setTimeout()` object. Thanks for the advice!

```
var iframeBody = $('body', $('#iframe')[0].contentWindow.document);
iframeBody.attr('contenteditable', true);
$(iframeBody).on('keyup', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(window.updatetimer)
    window.updatetimer = setTimeout(function(){
        savepagetext();
    },2000);
});
```